# Scandir() to show the newest folder

Tags: php, scandir

I basically have a form that creates a folder when submitted, it takes the last created folder (for example the folder name is 7) and creates a new map based on the last created folder (7+1) thus making a new folder named 8 etc. etc.

However when I create a map with the name 10 and echo `$latest_dir` it will still show 9.. whilst it should just show the highest number at all times.

```
$maindir = scandir("uploads/");
$latest_dir = $maindir[0];
$new_dir = $latest_dir+1;

echo $latest_dir;
```

I'm not really that good with PHP and this is the only thing that is not working so far.

Comment: This is due to regular sort vs natural sort. `10` is lower than `9` (as it starts with a `1`). You might be looking for [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'll check it out, i looks interesting!

Comment: @brancoholtslag Apologies then! h2oo is spot on though, `netsort` looks perfect for what you need :)

Comment: Hmm I tried but it still won't show anything above 9 :( @h2ooooooo

Comment: @brancoholtslag Have you used `print_r` on your array to see what it looks like?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes it echoed all in the right order (currently from 1 - 11) but when I tried echoeing $latest_dir it went back to 9 again

Comment: be careful about '.' and '..' folder that will be returner with the scandir function. I think the best solution is to filter folder name to ensure that you will only get number as folder name and to find the highest number, do not forget to cast to int your folder name

Comment: @brancoholtslag And you're sure that the `0` index includes the correct directory? If so, your code works. You must be doing something else wrong somewhere. Can you post the array to your original question with some code that *we* can test where it doesn't sort correctly?

Comment: Thanks guys, instead of using natsort I used rsort, it works like a charm now :) I'll post the change I made in the code as the answer.

Thanks for everyones help and special thanks to @h2ooooooo

Comment: @brancoholtslag If `rsort` works for you, `$array[count($array) - 1]` probably would too.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, I don't have tested it but I think it works.

```
$maindir = scandir("uploads/");

//remove '.' and '..' folder you can also use a regex to be sur to have only folder with
// number after filter
$mainDir = array_filter($maindir, function ($fileName) {
   if ($fileName !== "." || $fileName !== "..") {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else {
      return FALSE;
   }
}

$maxNumber = 0;

// Browse the array in order get the highest number (maybe you could use natsort() instead
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($mainDir) ; $i++) {
   if($maxNumber > (int) $mainDir[i]) {
      $maxNumber = (int) $mainDir[i];
   }
}

$new_dir = $maxNumber + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already managed to fix my problem using rsort()

See my answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem fixed, the folders were not ordered correctly, I changed my code to this:

```
$maindir = scandir("uploads/",1);
rsort($maindir);
$latest_dir = $maindir[0];
$new_dir = $latest_dir+1;
```

It orders the folders correctly and always shows the highest folder name.
Thanks for everyone's help :)